# Extracting/Copying selected data from HTML(web) table and removing unwanted column - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a macro that will extract/copy data from HTML(web) table to Excel and removing certain columns and copying specific data from the copied HTML table. The process will be;

1. Highlight the whole HTML table then copy.
2. Click button to paste into excel. (paste order must be based on the letter above each columns)

Please help as I am new to VBA.

This would be the format in excel;

```
-              a               b              c               d
```

[image: excel]

While this is the tabled HTML (sample only). The HTML table has 10 rows per page, also the date column has text content but i only need date and time - somehow it needs only to filter 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' data.

```
-          a       c       -       -       -       -       -       b      -        d
```

[image]

I have here a sample code:

```
Sub Paste()

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      Range("XEY1").Select
      ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

      y = 4 
      While Not Range("A" & y) = ""
            y = y + 1
      Wend

      d = Range("XEY3")
      Range("A" & y) = Replace(Mid(d, InStr(d, "(") + 5, InStr(d, ")") - InStr(d, "(") - 5), " CET", "")
      Range("F" & y) = Range("XEY11")
      Range("G" & y) = Range("XEY18")


      ActiveSheet.Range("XEY1:XEY50").Clear

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Transpose? Or just copy?

Comment: Can you put the column labels (a, b, c, d, etc.) above your excel format sample? Would make it easier to follow what you are trying do looking at that macro recorder code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think it would be transpose since I need to change the position/order of the copied data. -- but the recorded macro i created wouldn't automate the result i wanted to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out how this would happen.

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Button11_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim j As Integer, b As Integer, r As Integer, g As String

Range("XET1").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="HTML", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:= _
False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True

j = 6
b = 1

For r = 5 To 1000
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 5).Value <> "" Then

        Range("C" & j).Value = Range("XEU" & b).Value
        g = Range("XEV" & b)
        Range("E" & j).Value = Replace(Mid(g, InStr(g, "(") + 5, InStr(g, ")") - InStr(g, "(") - 5), "CEST", "")
        Range("D" & j).Value = Replace(Mid(g, InStr(g, "") + 38, InStr(g, ")") - InStr(g, "(") + 25), "REQ", "")
        Range("F" & j).Value = Range("XFD" & b).Value

    j = j + 1
    b = b + 1
   End If
Next r

ActiveSheet.Range("XET1:XFD50").Clear
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```